# Does ES2015 exported class create a closure?

Tags: javascript, class, module, closures, ecmascript-6

As it's currently compiled via Babel + Webpack, module's exported class will create a closure: variables created inside the module will be shared between class instances.

`bar.js`:

```
let foo;

export default class Bar {
    set foo(value) {
        foo = value;
    }
    get foo() {
        return foo;
    }
}
```

`app.js`:

```
import Bar from './bar.js';

var barOne = new Bar();
var barTwo = new Bar();

barOne.foo = 'quux';
console.assert(barTwo.foo === 'quux');
```

I wonder if this behavour correct according to the spec.

Comment: What happens if you do `this.foo == value` instead? :)

Comment: In the setter. I'd say `foo` is a class (aka static) property while `this.foo` is an instance one.

Comment: Wait. I didn't even see `let foo;` there. Of course it's the same across both classes. This example has nothing to do with classes actually, but with the way modules (`export` and `import`) are supposed to work

Comment: @Sergiu: It doesn't have anything to do with modules either.

Comment: foo is a variable inside a module. That whole module is shared everywhere. Yes, the whole modules thing does not add any "magic" here. If you `export foo` and `import` it elsewhere it'll be `=== 'quux'` too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder if this behavour correct according to the spec.

Yes. JavaScript has lexical scope. That doesn't change with classes.

Keep in mind that classes are more or less just syntactic sugar for constructor function + `prototype`. Would you have had the same question if you wrote

```
let foo;

function Bar(){};

Bar.prototype = {
    set foo(value) {
        foo = value;
    }
    get foo() {
        return foo;
    }
};

module.exports = Bar;
```

instead?